# Power BI Date Range Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with accounts and when they were active that looks like this:

| user | active_start | active_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2023 | 12/31/2023 |
| B | 2/5/2023 | 10/31/2023 |
| C | 5/11/2023 | 6/28/2023 |

I want to create a Power BI dashboard where a user can see how many users were active at some point during a date range of their choosing.
For example, if they need to know how many users were active from 1/1/2023 - 3/1/2023 it would show 2. If they wanted to select 4/1/2023 - 12/31/2023 it would show 3.

How can I accomplish this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have just the one slicer, and/or allow the user to select a month etc... then you will need a Date table for your model that you will use for your slicer.
An example Date table could be created with these steps:

1. Create a Calculated Table (via `New Table` under the `Modeling` tab in the ribbon) with the following:

```
DateTable = 
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Month", FORMAT([Date], "MMM"),
    "MonthNum", MONTH([Date]),
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "Year-Month", FORMAT([Date], "yyyy-MM")
  )
```

2. Once created, click on the `Month` column in the `DateTable`, then `Sort by column` in the ribbon, and select `MonthNum`. This will ensure Jan, Feb etc... will be ordered correctly.
3. Right-click on `DateTable` and select `Mark as date table` and in the pop-up select `Date` as the Date column.

That's your date table created. Next, ensure no relationship exists between the date table and your table. Then create a Measure with:

```
Active User count = 
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('YourTable'[user]),
    'YourTable'[active_start] <= MAX(DateTable[Date]) &&
    'YourTable'[active_end] >= MIN(DateTable[Date])
  )
```

For your slicer, use the `DateTable[date]` and set it to `Between`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes possible, or very close. Using below approach you have to slightly modify slicer to be a non-inclusive range. So for `1/1/2023` to `12/31/2023` you'd have to essentially specify `after 12/31/2022` and second slicer `before 1/1/2024`

## Steps To Create

### Create Measure

Anything to count users.
`ActiveCount = COUNT(DataTBL[User])`

### Create First Slicer

- Reference `active_start` field.
- Change the Slicer Settings → Style → to be `Before`
- Create a slicer heading stating *Ending Before* (or whatever seems informative)

[image]

### Create Second Slicer

Essentially same as above but inverse and other field.

- Reference `active_end` field.
- Change the Slicer Settings → Style → to be `After`
- Create a slicer heading stating *Start After*

[image]

### Final Result

Adding a visual you should see the results you expected in your output. Below are screenshots along with detailed view so match example. I probably should have changed the order of the two slicers and given better descriptions, but functionally the result works.

#### All Members (no filter)

Note I added two members before and after 2023 to give full range on starting selection.

[image]

#### 1/1/2023 to 3/1/2023

[image]

#### 4/1/2023 to 12/31/2023

[image]